# Error with PECL command in PHP7

Tags: 14.04, php

I've upgraded php to version 7 and now I have problems with pecl command. When I run sudo pecl install mongo I get long list of errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
```

I've tried solutions from this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors but it's not working. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP7, I installed `php-dev` package

Comment: Same situation :/

Comment: **Please help me, I need to install PECL using Unix ** https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362340/how-to-install-php-trader-pecl-using-unix?r=SearchResults&s=11|50.0164

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem as well when using 7.1 and after upgrading `pecl` through `apt-get`. I solved this by installing the `php7.1-xml` package using `apt-get`.

If you're running 7.0, then you need to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

If you're running 7.1, then run this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

That should solve your issue. It seems that PEAR parses help text and config info at startup and (I'm assuming) it's stored as XML somewhere

Comment: Fixes the problem also on Ubuntu 16 with php7.2, thanks.

Comment: In the case you are using php 7.3 run `sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml`